# Append my own json inside a json api request

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've like to apply additional information to my api request hence I've created a Json object with Characters and Actors to apply to the api's data with title, image and release date.

What I've done so far:
Fetched my own Json
Created a getjson function with the api and then i'm appending my own json into a loop to iterrate all 10 objects.
I'm also appending the api json into a ul li and in the end I would like to add my own Json with a div #id

```
  //now we are querying and prepare the results for display;
 $(document).ready(function(){
fetch("json/Metadata.json").then(async data => {
    var myjson = await data.text();
    myjson = JSON.parse(myjson);

$.getJSON(omdb_request, function(results){
    console.log(omdb_request);
    console.log(myjson);
    console.log(myjson.Movie1.Title);

    $.each(results.Search, function(idx, item){
        for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            
            $('#myjson'+[i]+'').append("Title - " + myjson.Movie[i].Title + "</br> ");
            $('#myjson'+[i]+'').append("Characters - " + myjson.Movie[i].Characters + "</br> ");
            $('#myjson'+[i]+'').append("Actors - " + myjson.Movie[i].Actors + "</br> ");
            $('#myjson'+[i]+'').append("Directed by - " + myjson.Movie[i].DirectedBy + "</br> ");
            $('#myjson'+[i]+'').append("Produced by - " + myjson.Movie[i].ProducedBy);

        };

                $('ul.movie_list').append('<li><p><strong>Title:</strong> '+results.Search[idx].Title+'</p><p><strong>Year:</strong> '+results.Search[idx].Year+'</p><img src="'+results.Search[idx].Poster+'" alt="'+results.Search[idx].Title+'"</img><div id="myjson'+[i]+'"</li>');
            
        }); //End $.each        
    }); //End $getJson
}) // End Fetch
}) // End Ready function
```

The error which applies to my file is line omdbapi.js line 29 This is the start of appending my own data into the div.

[image: Inspector tool]

Can you help me to see what's going on and why?

Comment: Replace `myjson.Movie[i]` with `myjson[`Movie${i}`]` as your keys are composed of `Movie` followed by a number.

Comment: thanks for the comment I dont know if i've done it right but     $('#myjson'+[i]+'').append("Title - " + myjson[Movie${i}].Title + "</br> "); Chrome dectects a unexscepted { in the first line of my appendings

Comment: Oops my comment got formatted incorrectly, I meant `myjson[\`Movie${i}\`]`

Comment: Omg you were right! Thanks. But right now i have all the looped data fra my own Json data within the first div instead of they split up do you have any ideas here ? :/